# Low side driver for unipolar stepper motor (voltage drop or current limiter)

Tags: stepper-motor, driver

I need drive unipolar stepper motor which resides in device with center coil pins connected internally together.

[image: Unipolar motor schema]

So I cannot change to bipolar driver. I use ULN2003 which works and I drive it with 5V, coil resistance is 50ohm, i.e. current (2x) 0.1A.

[image: Driver]

But I found the motor has unsufficient torque and started investigation what voltage is used in original aparatus. Seems they drive it with 15.5V.

[image: Measured voltage at motor coil]

Problem I have only 24V and 5V in my device available. The motor is rather crap, looks as from a cheap toy. I do not think it is good idea to drive from 24V (-1V drop at driver transistor). It also break limit of ULN2003 which has max. current 300mA.
I cannot find a low side driver with current sensing which could limit coil current. I have no space to implement regular PSU at my PCB and also price is important. So I am considering a few options:

1. undervoltage on input pins to cause not fully opened Darlington and force a voltage drop. CONS it probably causes overheating in driver.
2. serial diodes at COM to drop using forward diode voltage, CONS: string is long
3. Zener diode, CONS those diodes in SMA package have only 1W
4. current limiter to limit current flowing to COM to 300mA. There are fed one or two coils so it is not perfect but on the other side it should equal torque
5. LDO 24V -> 15V

What would you recommend to overcome this issue ?

Comment: You can’t use pwm with 24V supply?

Comment: Do you mean put FET with low Rds between 24V and COM and control ratio by PWM? Sounds good. What about current limits at driver, is it ok or a bulk capacitor is required ? Also is not issue Vg as it should be higher than Vs which is high. Unfortunately there are no 8 driver ICs to parallel Darlingtons.

Comment: Ya, driving phases with 4 mosfets. Linear current limiting drains power and generates heat.

Comment: Btw, old motors have poor torgue because of poor magnets  used those days. Now PM are much better.

Comment: How about using L298? It also has a current sense pin. You can put a high power resistor there to limit the current.